# installing R 3.3.3 on Ubuntu 17.04: yet another configuration error due to pcre

Tags: r, ubuntu, pcre

Downloading the R source and running `./configure` results in

```
checking whether PCRE support suffices... configure: error: pcre >= 8.10 library and headers are required
```

But `sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev` gives me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libpcre3 is already the newest version (2:8.39-3).
libpcre3-dev is already the newest version (2:8.39-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Find the version of pcre you installed. Might be pcre 8.0. You need version 8.10 or higher as the error message tells you.

Comment: I thought the output above said I had 8.39. Is there a way to check the version that R is looking for? It may be seeing an outdated copy.

Comment: I'm not sure it is actually 8.39. I have Kubuntu 14.04LTS (in VirtualBox) and had to install pcre 8.38 extra (in /usr/local) even though [ubuntu-packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpcre) says that 14.04 has 8.31. What those numbers actually mean: I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I did not enable UTF-8 support when I installed pcre from the source. Step 9C [this post](http://pj.freefaculty.org/blog/?p=315) cleared it up. [The post](http://pj.freefaculty.org/blog/?p=315) is the best guide I have found for installing R on Linux, but getting curl to compile with ssl was still a pain.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you insist on compiling from source when [these prebuilt binaries of R 3.3.3](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html)  exist?  I run them on three different sets of machines (and happen to be the one uploading the Debian builds upon which they are based).  Ditto with pcre---why do you think you get better builds when you force to do it yourself?  I am happy to outsorce to the maintainers who tend to know more about 'their' packages than I do.

Comment: Beforehand, I had tried `sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev` and got 3.3.2.  And I intend to concurrently install R-devel anyway, so I thought I might as well get my system ready. Otherwise, I would like to use package managers and prebuilt binaries as much as possible.

Comment: You get 3.3.2 from the distro -- but current once from the "community repo" at CRAN, ie a week from now it will have 3.4.0 for you.  And Michael has over 3000 other r-cran-* binaries in additional PPA repos should you need them.   And yes, r-devel I also build from source--but also maintain two Docker containers for it.